# How To Create An Extension Method In C# Using A Predicate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, extension-methods

I'm trying to create an extension method called RemoveWhere that removes an item from a List collection based on a predicate. For example

var result = products.RemoveWhere(p => p.ID == 5);

I'm using  Microsoft's Where extension method signature as a starting point. Here's what I have so far:

```
public static List<T> RemoveWhere<T>(this List<T> source, Func<T, List<T>> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source", "The sequence is null and contains no elements.");
    }

    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate", "The predicate function is null and cannot be executed.");
    }

    // how to use predicate here???

}
```

I don't know how to use the predicate. Can someone help me finish this? Thank you!

Comment: Let's start by criticizing what you have so far. Why does the method return a list? Does it return a *new* list with items removed, and keeps the source list unchanged? or does it remove the items from the source list? If the former, you have mis-stated what your method does. If the latter, then what is the meaning of the returned value? Why return anything at all?

Comment: Next, why does the predicate take an item and return a list of items? By definition a *predicate* is a function that returns *bool*.

Comment: Err, you could just be using a `System.Predicate` type instead.

Comment: Use the RemoveAll method of list. It takes a predicate as a paremeter. See my answer below

Comment: And third, *why are you doing this in the first place*? If this a learning exercise then that's great -- figuring out how you would write functionality that already exists is an excellent way to learn about that functionality. But if you're doing it for real-world work, why are you not using List<T>.RemoveAll? That appears to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Fourth, (assuming this is a learning exercise) do you have performance constraints? For example is the list extremely long, and are you going to be removing a lot of elements from its beginning? That can be *extremely* inefficient because every subsequent element needs to be "moved down" every time an element is removed from a mutable List<T>. If this is the sort of operation you do a lot, you might consider using a Set instead of a List; sets are much more efficient about removing items, but you don't get the items in any particular order as a result.

Comment: Yes this is entirely for learning purposes. I'm aware of RemoveAll and wanted to create a similar method for small lists that returns a list with the item removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Predicate parameter should be: `Func<T,bool>`

```
public static List<T> RemoveWhere<T>(this List<T> source, Func<T, bool > predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source", "The sequence is null and contains no elements.");
    }

    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate", "The predicate function is null and cannot be executed.");
    }

    // how to use predicate here???
    var result = new List<T>();
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        if(!predicate(item))
        {
            result.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**EDIT:** As others have pointed out, this method is either misnamed, or it already exists on List. My guess is just that you're trying to understand how a passed in delegate is used by the method itself. For that you can look at my sample. If that is not your intent, I'll delete this answer as the code really is kind of pointless.

Comment: This also does not do deferred execution, that might not be expected by a caller.

Comment: Well, if he's expecting a concrete List<T> back, how would you defer execution?

Comment: I wasn't aware that a predicate returns a boolean result. That and your code helped me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: @BFree May I inquire as to the reasoning behind the (! NOT) on the predicate conditional? Would it not need to be true for it to be a valid actionable item?

Comment: @BFree nevermind, i lost track of the context of the method along the way ;)

Answer (score 6):

There is already a method in list that does that try. Predicate should be a Predicate then you can use source.RemoveAll(predicate)

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, `List<T>.RemoveAll` will do what you want. If however, this is a learning experience or you want to operate on any `IList<T>` (which doesn't have `RemoveAll`) this should do the same as `RemoveAll` but as an extension method.

```
public static void RemoveWhere<T>(this IList<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
  //exceptions here...

  // how to use predicate here???
  for(int c = source.Count-1 ; c >= 0 ; c--)
  {
    if(predicate(source[c]))
    {
      source.RemoveAt(c);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A point of difference between this and the other answer with code is that this method mutates the original `IList<T>` as `RemoveAll` does while the other code does not and instead returns a new `List<T>`. The approach to take depends on the goal.

Answer (score 0):

As boca observed, `List<T>` already has a method to do this.  A somewhat larger issue, though, is that this really isn't a scenario where you should be creating a new extension method.  There's already an extension method that takes a predicate:  `Where`.

Granted, doing this:

```
var result = list.Where(x => x != 5).ToList();
```

is a little more code than using `RemoveAll`:

```
list.RemoveAll(x => x == 5);
```

But:

- it also builds a new list instead of modifying the existing list in place,
- `list` can actually be any `IEnumerable<T>`, not just a `List<T>`,
- the `Where` method is a commonly used, well-documented extension method that any reasonably-skilled C# programmer can be expected to recognize on sight
- it's clear to anyone reading that code that it's creating a new list, and
- if you don't *want* to create a new list, just leave off `ToList()` and enumerate over `result`.

It's really hard for me to envision circumstances where I'd want to write an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` that takes a predicate.  You're saving very little by making it possible for you to not use `Where()`.